# 500 error after deployment to remote server

Tags: php, symfony, server, ovh

I've finished my project with `Symfony2`, and I would like to deploy it on my server.

So, I've uploaded the files to the `www/` folder of my ovh server and configured the `parameters.yml`.

I don't have `ssh` access, only `ftp`.

When I go to `mywebsite.fr/web/config.php`, it works. But when I go to `mywebsite.fr/web/app.php` I got an error 500 whereas I've no problem in local.

Then, I tried several `.htaccess` files without results.

This is an example of `.htaccess` I found:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are the apache/nginx logs saying?

Comment: Please use \`code\` formatting instead of \*\*bold\*\* for file paths as it more readable.